# ¿Se puede usar un OR ó AND con un Switch?

Tags: c++, c

¿Podria hacer algo asi con C/C++?

```js
    var a = 8;
        
    switch(a){ 
     case a>=12:
      console.log("a");
     break;
        
     case a>1 || a<6:
      console.log("aa");
     break;
        
     default:
      console.log("aaa");
     break;
    }
```

intente con allgo parecido en C/C++ pero me genero un error al momento de compilar, algo como:

> el valor de 'a' no se puede usar en una expresi├│n constante
>   nota: 'int a' no es const

El codigo con el que intente era algo como:

```
int miVar;
char letra;

cout<<"Digite el valor:"<<endl;
cin>>miVar;


switch(miVar){

    case miVar<=30000:
    letra = 'A';
    break;

    case (miVar>30000 & miVar<=60000):
    letra = 'B';
    break;

    default:
    letra = 'C';
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No se puede, se tiene que usar un valor constante (definido en tiempo de compilación).

El error que te muestra es porque intenta interpretar la expresión que le pasas como constante y no puede.

Además, aunque *a* fuera constante, lo que te haría sería evaluar la expresión en compilación y te daría un valor booleano, y ese valor fijo sería el que compararía. No te usad curva porque en C/C++ los booleano son en realidad *integer*: en resultado sería equivalente a un *case 0* (si la expresión se evaluara a *false*) o *case [número distinto de 0]* si la expresión se evaluara a *true*.

Lo único parecido a un *or* sería poner los valores en varios *case* y no poner *break* entre ellos

```
switch (a) {
case 0: break;
case 1:
case 2:
case 3: // a esta línea se llega si a es 1, 2 ó 3, pero no 0
```

Comment: ¿Entonces se pueden usar variables ni Operadores Logicos en SWITCH con  C++? ¿donde podria leer mas sobre este tipo de restricciones?

Comment: No se puede usar variables porque son justo lo opuesto a constantes; en tiempo de compilación no se conoce su valor. Se pueden usar expresiones constantes (p.ej *case 7+2*), el compilador simplemente las evalúa al compilar el programa y te queda el mismo código que si hubiera usado su valor directamente (p.ej *case 9*).